# How can I install Test ToolKit on an existing Azure Container?

Tags: azure, powershell, dynamics-business-central

I have created a Business Central conatiner in Azure using

```
az container create `
    --resource-group 'RG-Container' `
    --name 'democontainer’ `
    --image mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral/sandbox:13.1.25940.26323 `
    --dns-name-label $'democontainer’ `
    --port 80
```

Once installed, how can i now add / install the testtoolkit ?
I dont see there being a -testtoolkit variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
-includeTestToolkit
```

Comment: I tried looking for this in the Microsoft Docs :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_container_create  couldnt see where this is valid ?     Also how can i check if the toolkit is installed ? Do i need to run the logs ?

Comment: It gives an error az : az: error: unrecognized arguments: --includeTestToolkit
At line:11 char:1
+ az container create -g $resourceGroup -n $containerName --image $imag ...